# Custom expression using property control

Tags: spotfire

I would like to know how to create calculated columns in my data set I have month and year column and cost column available using property control like to create below columns; 
1.full year 2015 - this column value be constant
2.ytd 2015 - this column total change based on selection
3.ytd 2016 - this column total change based on selection
4. Full year 2016 - this column total change based on selection

So I wanted to calculate these columns using custom expression and how to use property control in spotfire.

Comment: @ Vinoth Sairam - Could you please post a screenshot of your table?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I cannot able to add a photo since I am new to this forum.  Let me try to put some same table for you. Col 1 = sales col 2 = date col 3 = value ..... Based on this three column I need to calculate the columns.

Comment: I don't mean to sound rude but there are help links all over the page, so "I cannot since I'm new" is really lazy. the thing about StackOverflow is that you need to put effort into asking good questions. additionally, it's very difficult to understand what you're asking, so please can you try and ask in a different way?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I have tried it and calculated in those column on my own. If something is not known don't think that people without trying asking here. Also not everyone should know everything that does not like laziness. Thanks for your courtesy in giving this reply instead of answer for my question.

Comment: @VinothSairam if you want good help, you have to ask your question in a good way. it's not possible to answer your question well because it's not clear at all what you're asking. people answer on SO because we like to help people, but it's impossible to help someone who doesn't put any effort into getting help. read the HELP link that's literally right next to the comment box, and edit your question to make sense, and you will likely get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't enough information here for us to help you.  We need to know two main things --

1) What your data looks like (I can grasp this from your explanation, but if you don't know what you're doing in Spotfire itself, it makes it harder for us to get the code we're giving you correct)

2) How you want to display your data.  Ideally, this could be shown with a table or an image, with an example input and output.

MY BEST GUESS is that you want to display in a pivot table the full year's cost and the YTD cost for both 2015 and 2016.  I don't know what you mean by "based on a selection".

If you really do want a calculated column, and not a custom expression, the general format would be something like this:

```
If([Month] < Month(DateTimeNow()) and Year([Year]) = 2015, [Cost], 0)
```

This would allow you to sum up the 2015 YTD.

If this is not what you are looking for, please provide more explicit information.